# What is the problem in this multiple inheritance?

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, diamond-problem

```
class A:

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name

class B(A):

    def __init__(self,name,add):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.add = add

class C(A):

    def __init__(self,name,tel):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.tel = tel

class D(B,C):

    def __init__(self,name,add,tel,company):
        super().__init__(name,add)
        super().__init__(name,tel)
        self.company = company

d = D('Hank','ctm',55514,'google')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fERyp.png)

Comment: Show error message as properly formatted text in the question, not as image or external link.

Comment: You somehow expect that `super()` magically uses the right base class that fits your call. Once from `B` and on the next line the same call should use `C`.

Comment: Looks to me like the Deadly Diamond of Death of multiple inheritance.

Comment: @GuntherSchadow: That's not actually a problem in Python with properly written cooperative inheritance. Using the C3 linearization algorithm to produce a consistent, complete, non-repeating order for the parent classes in the method resolution order allows for each super class method to be called precisely once, even in diamond inheritance patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A resolution to this multiple inheritance is to cooperatively design the classes, see Raymond's article [Python’s super() considered super!](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/):

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, name, **kwargs):
        self.name = name

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, add, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add = add

class C(A):
    def __init__(self, tel, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.tel = tel

class D(B, C):
    def __init__(self, company, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.company = company

d = D(name='Hank', add='ctm', tel=55514, company='google')
```

As pointed out by others, this will follow the MRO, e.g. `D -> B -> C - A`.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the call to `super().__init__(name)` in the class `B`. Unlike single-inheritance languages such as Java, `super()` in Python doesn't necessarily give you the superclass; it gives you the next class in the [method resolution order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance). The MRO for class `D` is this:

```py
>>> D.__mro__
(<class '__main__.D'>,
 <class '__main__.B'>,
 <class '__main__.C'>,
 <class '__main__.A'>,
 <class 'object'>)
```

As you can see, the next class in the MRO after `B` is `C`, so the call to `super().__init__(name)` invokes `C.__init__` with a single argument. However, the `C.__init__` method expects two arguments, so calling it with just one argument results in the error you've seen.